# Is it possible to totally reskin the admin panel with a new template?

Tags: theme

Can the control panel have a skin or theme applied without it affecting automatic updates?

Answer (score 9):

You can certainly override the admin css by using https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss from Double Secret Agency. It's rather nice.

Lindsey also has a Admin JS plugin too: https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs

Regarding actual admin template changes and their ability to survive an update, I'll have to defer that to somebody who know's more about it than myself.

Answer (score 6):

No files within craft/app/ are safe to modify if you intend to keep Craft updated, including the templates.

Plus, the license forbids it, so there’s that.

Comment: I couldn't see anything in the license that would forbid it.